# A real-valued function on $X$ can define a real-valued function on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ by taking infimum. What's this process from a categorical POV?

Tags: category-theory

Let $X$ be a set with some order, and $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ be a function preserving the order. Consider the function $\tilde{f} : \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ defined by $$\forall A \in \mathcal{P}(X) : \tilde{f}(A) = \inf_{a \in A}\ f(a).$$

From a categorical POV, what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order on $X$ plays no role here. The functor $X \mapsto P(X)$ exhibits $P(X)$ as the free [complete suplattice](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/suplattice) on $X$; that is, it's left adjoint to the forgetful functor from complete suplattices to sets. Since $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \pm \infty \}$ is a complete suplattice (equipped with $\text{inf}$ as the suplattice operation), by the universal property, maps $X \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \pm \infty \}$ are the same thing as complete suplattice maps $P(X) \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \pm \infty \}$, with the correspondence given by taking infs.